# How to determine a formal root of a polynomial in power series over finite field?

Tags: functions, number-theory, finite-fields

I am looking for whether there is an easy way to define $y=\sqrt{-1}$ in $A_v$, where $A_v$ is the local ring with $A$ is the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ and $v$ is a prime ideal generated by a irreducible polynomial $x^2+1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. That is $y^2 = q-1 + (q-1)(x^2+1) + (q-1)(x^2+1)^2 + (q-1)(x^2+1)^2 +\cdots$. Then I would like to expand other power series in $\mathbb{F}_q[[x]]$ or just polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ in terms of a power series in $x - y$, i.e. $f(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-y) +a_2(x-y)^2+\cdots$, where $a_i\in\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ with degree less than $2$.

Moreover, is there an direct way to express $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: ...and you're trying to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: That local ring (after edit) is a subring of $\Bbb{F}_q(x)$. The sum formula for a geometric series says that
$$y^2=-1-(x^2+1)-(x^2+1)^2-\cdots=-\frac1{1-(x^2+1)}=\frac1{x^2}.$$ So $y=\pm 1/x$. Is that what you were after? Observe that this series is NOT an element of $\Bbb{F}_q[[x]]$. It is defined as an element of $\Bbb{F}_q[[x^2+1]]$. Above I viewed it as an element of $\Bbb{F}_q(x)$, but not all power series are rational functions (as I'm sure you know).

Comment: Because $\sqrt{-1}$ is algebraic over the field of constants you are just expanding your field of constants.

Comment: By viewing $y$ as an element of $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ you can write any polynomial $p(x)\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ in terms of powers of $x-y$ simply because the set $(x-y)^i,i=0,1,2,\ldots$, is an $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$-basis of the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}[x]$. You can also write the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}(x)$ that have no poles at $y$ as a power series in $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}[[x-y]]$. But, the objection outlined in the (now obsolete) answer are in a sense about the difference between $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}[[x]]$ and $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}[[x-y]]$. I hope you know that those are not the same ring.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to do. This is too long to be a comment, so an answer it is. Please comment, and may be we can locate the question you really wanted to ask.

- If $q\equiv1\pmod4$, then the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ already contains a
  zero of the polynomial $x^2+1$, call it $i$. Even if
  $q\equiv3\pmod4$, then adjoining a zero of $x^2+1$ will give you the
  ring of formal power series over the extension field
  $\Bbb{F}_q[i]\simeq\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$.
- The polynomial $x^2+1$ is a unit of $\Bbb{F}_q[[x]]$: $$(1+x^2)^{-1}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots.$$ Therefore the ideal it generates is all of $\Bbb{F}_q[[x]].$
- The series (I replaced $q-1$ with $-1$ for the sake of brevity) $$-1-(x^2+1)-(x^2+1)^2-(x^2+1)^3-\cdots$$ does not make sense in the ring $\Bbb{F}_q[[x]]$. This is because all those terms have a non-zero constant term. And we cannot define the sum of infinitely many non-zero constants in $\Bbb{F}_q$ in any meaningful way. The only Hausdorff topology there is the discrete one, and the sum infinitely many non-zero terms simply never converges.
- The same objection applies to an infinite sum of powers of $(x-y)$. They all have a non-zero constant term, so the infinite sum does not make sense.

Comment: In my last bullet the objection is that, due to the first bullet, $y$ really is a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found that I made a mistake in the question, so I modified the question now.